# ionic - could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I am trying to build an APK file for my android project using ionic. But I am getting this error only. I tried all different things suggested on the internet, but nothing worked.

> Parsing D:\myApp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml failed
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file  or directory, open
>   'D:\myApp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml'

My ionic configuration iscli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.0
npm  : 6.3.0
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend: pro
```

If anyone knows the solution kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to remove Android platform and add platform again ?

Comment: Yes. More than 20-30 times I tried. Also, I removed the plugins folder, node_modules folder and rebuilt all again.

Comment: ok. Gradle is installed and ANDROI_HOME variable in your env set ?

Comment: Yes. I just added ANDROID_HOME variable before sometime.

Comment: humm Ok. did you tried to change your android version. Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 to 6.xx.xx

Comment: Yes. I deleted the android folder from platforms and tried to add android platform of version 6.4.0. But still getting the same error again.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: yes. I removed android folder using CLI and added it again. and it worked. !